# ScrollView doesn't scroll properly (bounces) in combination with Geometry Reader

Tags: swiftui, scrollview, geometryreader

I already reviewed the answer here ([ScrollView Doesn't Scroll with Geometry Reader as Child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63609287/scrollview-doesnt-scroll-with-geometry-reader-as-child)) which is I guess pretty similar but I wasn't able to figure it out.

My Goal is to show the images equally sized (quadratic).

Here's my View:

```swift
struct MyGeoView: View {
    
    let icons = ["bed.double.fill","tram.fill","tv.music.note.fill","hare.fill", "person", "clock", "plus", "trash", "home", "arrow", "pencil", "scribble", "folder", "folder.circle", "trash.circle", "paperplane"]
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader{ geo in
            ScrollView{
                GeometryReader{ geo in
                    LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible()), count: 3), spacing: 3 ){
                        ForEach(icons, id: \.self){ post in
                            Image(systemName: post)
                                .frame(width: geo.size.width/3, height: geo.size.width/3)
                                .background(Color.pink)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Unfortunately it's not scrolling properly (bounces) and always goes back to top. Do you have some ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need only one `GeometryReader`, external one.

Here is corrected code. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader{ geo in
        ScrollView{
            LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible()), count: 3), spacing: 3 ){
                ForEach(icons, id: \.self){ post in
                    Image(systemName: post)
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width/3, height: geo.size.width/3)
                        .background(Color.pink)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```